# Java scanner, how to read a text file line by line without always going to the next line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If I use the nextline() method in the scanner object, then it will take in that line and then go to the next one. Is there a way to read in the line and *not* go to the next line? Is there a different class to use that will read in a text file line by line and only go to the next line when told to, as opposed to automatically jumping to the next line once it has read in the current line?

Comment: you can use `.next()` and you can also specify delimiters . By default it will be space.

Comment: You can read a line into a string and then keep the string to refer to as many times as you like before you read the next line.

Comment: No, the Java classes mostly all use this idiom. You can write your own wrapper with a C#/C++ style interface, but emulating the API of a different language just because you're more comfortable with that is bad practice.

Comment: `Is there a different class to use that will read in a text file line by line and only go to the next line when told to`. Your code to read the text file should do this. If you need to process a file line after it is read then call a method to do so before moving onto the next line. If the file is small enough you can place each file line into an ArrayList and process each line as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67441145/java-scanner-how-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line-without-always-going-to-the-n#comment119204575_67441145) by Goion, you can change the delimiter (e.g. `useDelimiter("\\n")`) and use `next()`, which does not *consume* the delimiter (line separator).

Not sure what that is good for; be aware that most console input are *line-oriented*, that is, input will only be processed after user types the enter or return key - `Scanner` will block until that line is available.

Comment: I'm not reading from the console input, I have a written text document that I have to read in line by line and perform operations based on the data in the line. It seems to just skip lines whenever I try to perform logic based on the data taken in from the current line.